# How to fill in the blanks with user inputs in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am trying to get the user to fill in the blanks for multiple values in one sentence. The user should type inside of the statement, hence completing the blanks.

My code:

```
print("My name is       and I am     years old.", end="\r")
a = input("My name is ")
b = input("My name is       and I am ")
```

At the moment this results in:

[image: console]

How can I combine these into one line?
Expected outcome would be the user typing inside of the printed string, like so:

[image: console]

Comment: Could you post the result that you are expecting?

Comment: does my edit help?

Comment: Yes. What you want is probably achievable, but i don't think you want to implement it. Terminal shell is not that interactive. As you could've noticed, most programs expected user input on a new line for each entry. Same is for python. To do what you want you would probably need to use some terminal drawing. There is no conventional way to do that in 1 line - that is for sure

Comment: okay, thanks. would have been nice to have but i'll work around it.